# The $3×3$ representation of weak $SU(2)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, standard-model, group-theory, commutator, electroweak

I'm reading chapter 11.2 of the Cheng and Li textbook 'Gauge theory of elementary particle physics'. It  says that $T_+$, $T_-$ and $Q$ do not form a closed algebra. In order to fix this problem the theory is extended to contain extra fermions.

As Georgi and Glashow did, a heavy lepton $E$ is added to form a triplet together with a electron neutrino and electron. My question is about the commutator relation of $T_+$ with $T_-$. Can someone explain how they get to this commutator relation? In the book they say this relation is straighforward but I  can't see how they get it. See the pictures for clarity.

[image: from Cheng and Li textbook]

Comment: On the first line of (11.23), the symbol is supposed to be $E^\dagger$, and not $E^+$, in case that is what is confusing you. The operator destroys  neutral particles and creates positive charged new leptons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading this text and have advanced to that section, especially past its (11.20,21,22), you must be proficient in the standard QFT current algebra application of the [Jordan map for fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map#Fermions), and whence appreciate how
$$
J_{ +}=\sqrt{2} \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\ 0& 0& 1\\ 0&0&0&\end{pmatrix} ,\qquad J_+^\dagger =J_-, \quad J_3=\operatorname{diag} (1,0,1),\\
[J_+,J_-]=2J_3.
$$

Your Jordan map fermion sandwich (11.23) then follows directly for each of your $P_L$ and $P_R$ fermion isotriplet of (ii); note using the fermion anticommutation law between (11.20) & (11.21)  keeps the triplets apart, as cross terms die off by the orthogonal projection operators $P_L \& P_R$.

You then have inside the obvious respective integrals,
$$
[T_+, T_+^\dagger]\mapsto  2\left ( (E,N\sin\alpha+\nu \cos\alpha  ,e))^\dagger J_3 P_L(E,N\sin\alpha+\nu \cos\alpha  ,e)^T + (E,N,e)^\dagger J_3 P_R(E,N,e)^T   
\right) = 2 (E^\dagger (P_L+P_R)E - e^\dagger (P_L+P_R)e)=
2 (E^\dagger E - e^\dagger  e) \mapsto 2Q. 
$$
Note how the difference in the middle entry of the two isotriplets drops out by being multiplied by the vanishing eigenvalue of $J_3$!

Neat, huh?